# XAMPP PHP error Notice: "Undefined variable" from HTML to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

I am newbie learning PHP, and I think my problem is that I can't pass a variable value from HTML to PHP:

### I have one page, called form.php. Here it is its code, along with its HTML code as well:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>form</title>
  </head>
     <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
       <form action="page2.php" method=post> 
           My name is: <br>
           <input type="text" name="yourname"> 
              <p> Please leave your message here <br>
           <input type="text" name="message"> 
              <p>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please accept my   data!"> 
        </form>
      </body>
```

```
page2.php has this chunk instead in it:
```

---

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Hi!</title>
   </head>
        <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
           <p>
              Hi! <?php print $yourname; ?>
           <p>
              Thank you for your message  <b> <?php print $message; ?> !?! </b>
        </body>
```

The error I get is the following:

Notice: Undefined variable: yourname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test-Antonio\page2.php   on line 7
Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test-Antonio\page2.php on line 9

**So it seems that I am not able to pass varibles values from HTML to PHP**. Is it right? What I am supposed to do to make it run?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me on this!!
Best regards,
Antonio.

Comment: use <?php echo $_POST["yourname"]; ?>

Comment: What you try to do, would have worked a few years back, when `register_globals` was active. Nowadays, you access those variables using `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET`, and/or `$_POST`.

Comment: It's all in the manual, have a read: [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 1 should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>page 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="page2.php" method="post"> 
            <label>My name is: </label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="yourname"> <br/>
            <label> Please leave your message here:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="message"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please accept my data!"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 should be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>page 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi! <?php echo $_POST['yourname']; ?><p>
        <p>Thank you for your message  <b> <?php echo $_POST['message']; ?> !?! </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You should echo $yourname with

```
<?php echo $yourname ?>
```

OR

Also make sure you've assigned the $yourname variable. You can do that with

```
$yourname = "your name";
```

Or if you are working with a post mechanism:

```
$yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use **$_POST** to get the data passed via POST request

```
Hi! <?php echo $_POST["yourname"]; ?>
```

Your html form has method="post" attribute so it will pass all your input via POST request and can be accessible in PHP in `$_POST[<input name>]` variable.

If your form has no method attribute defined or has method="get" then it will be submitted via GET request and can be accessible in PHP via `$_GET[<input name>]`.

Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Learn about basic form handling in PHP and HTML please. You might want to learn ajax via javascript to tweak your forms. Have a read about ajax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo $_POST ["yourname']; ?>
```

Will resolve your error. Because you have not assigned a variable for `$yourname` PHP doesn't know what it's doing so will throw an error. I'd also recommend looking at the manual for the `$_POST` global

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get the variables from a form using `$_POST['variablesName']`. So in this case , use  `$_POST['yourname']` other than `$yourname`.